# (JAVA)How to Match up Strings including Japanese Characters to print out in Terminal with the same length

Tags: java, string, byte

I am trying to print out some data including names with Japanese characters and kanji in table view in Terminal. What I have done in another project was to find the maximum number of bytes of each column and adding white space to match up the bytes numbers for those that have less number of bytes than the column maximum. It worked fine on a Windows machine, however, when I try to implement this again on my mac, it doesn't work. I have got the following two questions:

1. Can anyone provide any clue on why this is happening? Is it because of the OS difference? Or any other reason might cause this?
   (Don't know if it relates to the problem, but the Windows machine I worked on was in Japanese and my mac is in English)
2. If it won't work, is there any other approaches that I can take to work this out? the best is that the same code can work on both OS.

Below is my example code:

```
class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String a = "sojdi";
        String b = "sじゃいおdw";
        while(a.getBytes().length<b.getBytes().length)
        {
            a = a+' ';
        }
        System.out.println("|"+a+"|");
        System.out.println("|"+b+"|");
        System.out.println("Bytes Number of a: " + a.getBytes().length);
        System.out.println("Bytes Number of b: " + b.getBytes().length);
    }
}
```

Result:
[image: Bytes number matches but print out with different length]

The number of Bytes matches but Strings are printed out differently in length. Any advice or any other approach to work this out? Thanks in advance.

### ------------------------------------------------------------

Update:

I have found a solution to this problem. Just in case someone may want to know the solution, and also to serve as a memo, I'll post my solution here.

Because of different Encoding, the bytes number for Japanese Characters is 3 and alphabet/white spaces is 1, but the character width is actually 2 for Japanese and alphabet/ white space 1. Consequently, each Japanese character I have will create a difference of 2 bytes rather than 1 which is what it should be in order to match the String width. However, when I implement this on Windows previously it was 2 and 1 bytes for Japanese and alphabet respectively(I believe). So, as someone has suggested but deleted his or her comment, I have adjusted my code as follows:

```
class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String a = "sojdi";
        String b = "s じゃいお青いdw";
        while(a.getBytes(Charset.forName("SHIFT-JIS")).length<b.getBytes(Charset.forName("SHIFT-JIS")).length)
        {
            a = a+' ';
        }
        System.out.println("|"+a+"|");
        System.out.println("|"+b+"|");
        System.out.println("Bytes Number of a: " + a.getBytes(Charset.forName("SHIFT-JIS")).length);
        System.out.println("Bytes Number of b: " + b.getBytes(Charset.forName("SHIFT-JIS")).length);
    }
}
```

And the result:
[image: result]

Comment: I think this is more of a problem with character width rather than the number of chars

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19045949/java-calculate-number-of-printed-characters-on-console-to-underline

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thanks a lot for your comment, and by the hint you gave me I realised that the problem is caused by encoding my mac and Japanese WindowsOS does. I have managed to fix it. Thanks again for your help